# 3D в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unity3d, github, 3d

Я довольно давно работаю с Android Studio, недавно мне довелось поработать с Unity, c 3D объектами. Так вот мне интересно, предположим я создал некий 3D объект в Blender. Есть ли такие библиотеки или инструменты, которые позволят мне работать с 3D в Android Studio?

Comment: Вы же не для AS собираетесь 3D плагины писать, а Андроид приложения, как я понимаю. Вам сюда. https://developer.android.com/games/develop/build-in-unity